# Mongoose add/append values inside array inside array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hello and sorry for the title, it is quite hard to explain with words.

I have data with multiple levels in the mongo collection.

I am trying to insert a value inside the `maps` array which is already inside `favorite_lists` array of objects. Below is the user collection schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60f3fdae2367163726c6716b"),
    "username" : "Johnny65",
    "first_name" : "Thaddeus",
    "last_name" : "Lueilwitz",
    "email" : "example@gmail.com",
    "mobile" : "834XXXX",
    "profile_photo" : "http://placeimg.com/640/480",
    "login_type" : 2,
    "maps_created" : ISODate("2020-04-08T20:00:28.453Z"),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2021-06-24T16:19:07.010Z"),
    "favorite_lists" : [
        {
            "maps" : [ ],
            "name" : "name 1",
            "created_date" : ISODate("2021-07-20T13:27:56.050Z")
        },
        {
            "maps" : [ ],
            "name" : "name 2",
            "created_date" : ISODate("2021-07-20T13:31:21.985Z")
        },
        {
            "maps" : [ ],
            "name" : "name 3",
            "created_date" : ISODate("2021-07-20T13:35:32.959Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to insert value inside `maps` array where `favorite_lists.name = "name 2"`

**Expected Result**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60f3fdae2367163726c6716b"),
        "username" : "Johnny65",
        "first_name" : "Thaddeus",
        "last_name" : "Lueilwitz",
        "email" : "example@gmail.com",
        "mobile" : "834XXXX",
        "profile_photo" : "http://placeimg.com/640/480",
        "login_type" : 2,
        "maps_created" : ISODate("2020-04-08T20:00:28.453Z"),
        "created_date" : ISODate("2021-06-24T16:19:07.010Z"),
        "favorite_lists" : [
            {
                "maps" : [ ],
                "name" : "name 1",
                "created_date" : ISODate("2021-07-20T13:27:56.050Z")
            },
            {
                "maps" : ["value 1", "value 2" ],
                "name" : "name 2",
                "created_date" : ISODate("2021-07-20T13:31:21.985Z")
            },
            {
                "maps" : [ ],
                "name" : "name 3",
                "created_date" : ISODate("2021-07-20T13:35:32.959Z")
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$` positional with `$addToSet` to append elements in array and `$each` for insert multiple elements,

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  "favorite_lists.name": "name 2"
},
{
  $addToSet: {
    "favorite_lists.$.maps": {
      $each: [
        "value 1",
        "value 2"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UR2zMZTaC4Y)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [positional operator `$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) into an update to modify the value you want.

```
yourModel.update({
  "favorite_lists.name": "name 2"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "favorite_lists.$.maps": {
      "$each": [
        "value 1",
        "value 2"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

This query says to mongo: "Find the document where exists `"favorite_lists.name": "name 2"` and push inside `favorite_lists.$.maps` (nothe how $ tells mongo which document inside array upadte) each value from the array".

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bR_d1H3b17Y)